# importing data in Hebrew to python

Tags: python, hebrew

Hello I am new to python.

I have a data frame called psagot which has one column called SHEM_NIYAR_HEB with values in Hebrew .When I import the data to python I get gibberish instead of the real values.

I read on the internet that the following code could help

```
encode('cp1252').decode('cp1255',errors='replace')
```

The code works well when I apply it to one value at a time for example the following code will fix the third value of the column SHEM_NIYAR_HEB

```
t=psagot.iloc[:,3]
t=t.iloc[3]
t=t.encode('cp1252').decode('cp1255',errors='replace')
```

The problem arises when I try to apply this for the entire column .This is the code :

```
t=psagot.iloc[:,3]
t=t.encode('cp1252').decode('cp1255',errors='replace')
```

The error I get states

```
AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Is there a quick way to change all values in the column.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: How are you importing your data, CSV?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try specifying the encoding when you import instead of changing it afterwards.

Assuming your data comes from a CSV file:

```
df = pd.read_csv('data_file.csv', encoding='cp1255')
```